# Get information about dependent modules in Ivy

Tags: ant, ivy

have several "generic" modules and one module, which is dependent on them (root). I would like to put some information in the generic modules ixy.xml and later read this information in the build.xml of the root. So the generic module ivy.xml looks like:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0"  xmlns:sqsg="http://www.company.com/sqsg/ivy/extra">
  <info organisation="company" module="build-scripts" revision="1.0.2" status="integration" sqsg:svnurl="blabla">
  </info>
  <publications>
   ...
  </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

I put and extra attribute "svnurl" to the ivy.xml. The root ivy.xml may look like:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="company" module="root" revision="2.0.5" status="integration">
    </info>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="company" name="build-scripts" rev="1.0+" changing="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

I want to read the value of the "svnurl" attribute of all dependencies after I made *ivy:resolve* of the root module. I tried to look at *buildlist* and *listmodules*, but it seems to me they lack the functionality I need. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will the [info](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/info.html) task help?:

```
<ivy:info organisation="apache" module="info-all" revision="1.0" />
```

- **ivy.artifact.[index].extra.[any extra attribute]**:    For each extra
  attribute of the published artifact, a property is created containing
  its name. (Since 2.2)

Comment: Seems that it works, thanks! (In fact, it is ivy.extra.[any extra attribute], but it doesn't matter.) I haven't noticed that the info task has the organisation and module attributes.